# Minetest won't install

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, software-installation

Every time I try to install Minetest from a .deb package, it says this afert

```
processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
errors were encountered while processing: /home/collinc/downloads/minetestc55_0.4.7-0ppal~raring1_i386.deb
```

I need 0.4.7, not 0.3.1 like they have in the software center. Any fixes?
I am running Lubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Where did you download that file? Can you include in your question the full error message?

Comment: that was it. it said a few other things, but it wouldve taken a while to type, and they were useless. just saying whats being configured and stuff.

Comment: i downloaded it from the offiall link on minetest.net

Comment: Can you post the full output anyway? Just to make sure. There is probably something useful in there.

Comment: i saved the pic, but dont have any way to post it. :(

Comment: @CollinC. click on "edit" at the bottom of the question, then you should see a button in the toolbox named "img". Click on it, and then the rest should be straightforward =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~minetestdevs/+archive/stable

To do this, open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), and run this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minetestdevs/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge minetest* # Remove the old packages
sudo apt-get install minetestc55
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Ive tried that. and i tried it again. this is what it says... coming up as soon as i finsih wrighting it.

Comment: @CollinC. so I take it that it didn't work? Could you post the full error message? If it's hard to post on here, post it on somewhere like imgur.com (or pastie.org if you're pasting text)

Comment: dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/minetestc55_0.4.7-0ppa1~raring1_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwright 'usr/share/applications/minetest.desktop', which is also in package

Comment: `which is also in package`...? Was there anything else after that? If not, dpkg is trolling us (we'll have to find some other way to do it) XD

Comment: minetest0.3.1 +dfsg-4   No apport report written because MaxReport is reached already                   it does go on a little more with a similiar message i got in the begining without using terminal.

Comment: @CollinC. Okay, I updated the answer. Try running `sudo apt-get purge minetest` and then run `sudo apt-get install minetestc55`

Comment: i tried, but it came up with the same error last time (i didnt post that one. it came after the one i posted)      Errors were encountered while procesing: /var/cache/apt/archives/minetestc55_0.4.7-0ppa1~raring1_i386.deb             E: sub process usr/bin/dpkg returned and error code (1)

Comment: @CollinC. okay, try running `sudo apt-get purge minetest* minetestc55` _then_ run `sudo apt-get install minetestc55`. Notice the `*` symbol after `minetest`. That is so that all minetest packages will be removed

Comment: i think it worked. ill test it and tell you if it did

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!!! Though I spawned in a place where EVERYTHING is red. I dunno if thats normal. ANyways, thanks! -brohoof-

Comment: @CollinC. That's because your graphics card doesn't support shaders. Disable shaders in the settings menu, and things should work fine! Also, not exactly related to the question, but I'd also recommend you checking out terasology too (http://terasology.org/) =)   (\

Comment: @CollinC. If this answer solved your question, click the checkmark next to it. This will mark the answer as "This solved the question".